# Create List using Button

Tags: javascript, html

I want to create a list li under ul that having 2 label and 1 text box. It should be create dynamically in HTML when a button clicks using JavaScript. As I am not aware of Jquery, please let me know in JavaScript.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not a free coding service... You should show us what you tried before asking for help.

Comment: Its a good question, but we can help out you till you show written. Let me Know where is the error u r getting using code.

Answer (score 0):

I have made an example to help you on your way. It's not the best code, but it might give you the right idea to get on track. [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Jorrex/jvujm219/)

```js
document.getElementById("createList").addEventListener("click", createList, false);
var items = document.getElementById("items");
var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
var ul = document.createElement("ul");

function createList() {
  items = parseInt(items.value);
  for (var i = 0; i < items; i++) {
    var label1 = document.createElement("label");
    label1.innerHTML = "Label 1";

    var label2 = document.createElement("label");
    label2.innerHTML = "Label 2";

    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "text");

    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.appendChild(label1);
    div.appendChild(input);
    div.appendChild(label2);


    var li = document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(div);
    ul.appendChild(li);
  }

  wrapper.appendChild(ul);
}
```

```css
label {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
input {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<button id="createList">
  Create list
</button>
Amount of items:
<input type="text" id="items" />
<div id="wrapper">
</div>
```